# Android Json Get URL STOPPED

Tags: android, json, url, android-asynctask, opendata

I just started the topic to get data from a JSON OpenData and visualize via my phone.

I followed this tutorial and it has worked all :)

https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-asynctask-json-parsing-example.html 
The url whew i get the datas is :

http:// + api.learn2crack.com/android/json/ (sorry for that, I don't have a good reputation :) )

Then I wanted to try a Opendata me and my android application stops, the url is:

[http://ckan.opendata.nets.upf.edu/storage/f/2013-11-30T16%3A49%3A59.118Z/london.json](http://ckan.opendata.nets.upf.edu/storage/f/2013-11-30T16:49:59.118Z/london.json)

You can see it's the same and I only change the name of URL in the code.
You know if the problem is because of the OpenData? and I need some permission? Because when I execute the second part my app stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this will work. I am using Strict Policy but normally you should use Async. Please google this as to why we should use Async instead of Strict Policy. This is irrelevant here

When i am using HttpPost to get your json from url, i am getting these errors :-

**405 Method Not Allowed**

**The method POST is not allowed for this resource.**

**You cannot POST a file**

so i am using HttpGet :-

```
        String url = "http://ckan.opendata.nets.upf.edu/storage/f/2013-11-30T16:49:59.118Z/london.json";

    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        JSONArray json2 = json.getJSONArray("user");

        for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject c = json2.getJSONObject(i);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```